# Конвертирование изображений в видео и трансформация в поток C#

Tags: c#, .net, потоки-данных, видео

Хочу попробовать поработать с медиафайлами и видеопотоками ради спортивного интереса. Из всего что нашел, это gstreamer и ffmpeg фреймворки. Существует ли альтернатива? И даже вроде бы популярный gstreamer, а примеров на C# практически нет. 
На данный момент спортивная задача такая, взять медиа файлик в директории на сервере (либо сервис, либо Web Api, не знаю как правильно), конвертировать его и потоком по TCP или HTTP передать клиенту. А на клиенте уже плеер будет транслировать этот видеопоток.